# iOS 8 project using Cocoa Touch Framework doesn't build in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios8

I have created a Cocoa Touch Framework using XCode 6 and I am using it in my latest project which has been built and created with the same version of XCode. Both projects Deployment Targets are iOS 8.1.

When I try to build my app while using the framework in simulator, I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_WBATranslations", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in RIAccountsViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Project builds all fine when I compile on a device which makes me think the framework architectures are not correct. The default settings of the framework is on the image here:
[image]

What do I have to do to be able to build for both, device, as well as simulator?

Comment: Is the file containing the definition of  `WBATranslations` included in the framework target?

Comment: Is `WBATranslations` part of the framework?  If so, the framework may not have been created for the simulator architecture. (x86_64 vs. arm... types)

Comment: WBATranslations are included and available ... like I mentioned, the library archives all ok but when I include it in another project, it won't build for simulator, only on a device

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to launch a framework which compiled for devices only on your simulator.

Please check this [Tutorial](http://locomoviles.com/ios-tutorials/create-ios-cocoa-touch-framework-using-xcode/), section **Building the Framework**, you need to drag framework for simulator.

Also you can try to find some tutorials for creating **Universal** framework. For example you can check [this one](https://medium.com/@syshen/create-an-ios-universal-framework-148eb130a46c)

Comment: That will build a fat binary that will be most likely rejected now. I have looked at this: https://kodmunki.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/cocoa-touch-frameworks-for-ios8-remix/ but haven't been able to make it work yet :(

Comment: Building the Framework link is dead. Avoid linking 3rd party websites without including relevant content from them in your answer.